# is it possible to remove the logo in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Is there way to set the logo for a 2010 SharePoint site as "none"?

[image: Logo]

Comment: You could hide it with CSS.  I don't have SP2010 available right now or I would investigate more for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a 100% transparent PNG or GIF graphic at your desired size and load this in as the site icon by going to "Site Actions > Site Settings > Title, Description and icon".

Answer (score 0):

I found it easy to locate and comment-out the Logo section in the CSS. Worked well, as we have a `custom banner .jpg` that already includes an imbedded logo.